# Bot doesn't send the requested message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a support bot, but it doesn't exactly how expected. Instead of going straight to DMS, the bot sends the message in the trigger. When I run the command, I have to put a message before it DMS me. Then it runs through all of the steps, but after I dm it something else, it sends the original context message.

```
@bot.command()
async def contact(ctx, *, message):
  channel = bot.get_channel(766311471063498852)
  embed1 = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.blue())
  embed1.add_field(name="Your support lays behind this bot.", value="Do you need support?", inline=True)
  embed_1sent = await ctx.author.send(embed=embed1)
  embed2 = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.blue())
  embed2.add_field(name="Alright.", value="What would you like to send to staff?", inline=True)
  await embed_1sent.add_reaction("<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>")
  await embed_1sent.add_reaction("<a:XMark:768095331555606528>")
  def check(reaction, member):
    return member == member and str(reaction.emoji)== "<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146>"

  try:
   reaction, member = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
  except asyncio.Timeout.Error:
    await member.send("You took too long. Command cancelled.")
  else:
    await member.send(embed=embed2)
    await channel.send(f"From: {member} {message}")
  def check(reaction, member):
    return member == member and str(reaction.emoji)== "<a:XMark:768095331555606528"

  try:
    reaction, member = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
  except asyncio.Timeout.Error:
    await member.send("You took too long. Command cancelled.")
  else:
    await member.send("Command promt cancelled.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to DM a user is with the `.create_dm()` method. So when sending your embeds, you should have something more like this.

```
embedOne = discord.Embed(
    color = discord.Color.Blue()
)

embedOneadd_field(name = "Your support lays behind this bot.", value = "Do you need support?", inline = True)

userDM = ctx.author.create_dm()
embedOneMessage = await userDM.send(embed = embedOne)
```

Comment: This does work for me but I came across the same issue with my first attempt. It requires a message in the trigger message, then goes through the process of DMing you before sending the message.